# User experience with multilanguage website

Tags: search-engine, social-networking, multilingual, user-experience

I'm creating a website that is a kind of search engine of registered customers. 
Out of three offered languages, the customers can choose a default one, just like the visitors.

When a visitor visits a profile of a registered customer, the employer wants the language of the entire website's interface to be changed to a customer's language.

What would be the advantages and disadvantages of this idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's a really bad idea to guess at a language preference regardless of where the data comes from.**

As a general rule the viewer's language preference should take priority. If you don't respect this rule, at best you'll annoy a viewer who has to work harder to understand something. At worst you'll make your site completely un-usable for that person.

There really aren't pro's to letting a system decision, or other data setting determine a language, especially when it impacts the entire interface. Instead, you should provide a consistent option (header or footer) to change localization settings AND respect that for at least the entire session.

---

*As a side note:* This sounds like a request based on perceived problems and solutions. I would dig to find the real problem and then brainstorm other solutions that don't involve forced language changes. I would also talk to users and get real data. Don't let the business dictate how users want to interact.

Answer (score 0):

This idea might confuse your visitor user and breaks one of the 10 usability heuristics for UI Design: "Visibility of system status". The user should be able to understand what's going on at any time.

Nowadays, apps can detect your device's language settings and display the content for you in the same language. And in this particular case it is intuitive -the user doesn't even realize this is happening. But in your case, you are taking choices for a visitor that the user doesn't know. Maybe you are trying to solve other problem, but you will gain a new one.

You might wanna take a look to those heuristics:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/